# Xceed.Wpf.Toolkit.PropertyGrid.PropertyGrid: Locally created object belongs to a different thread?

Tags: c#, wpf, multithreading, wpftoolkit, xceed

Just look at it, it doesn't make any sense:

[image]

The objects are created locally with no external dependencies. How can it be?

(The type created here is a `Xceed.Wpf.Toolkit.PropertyGrid.PropertyGrid`)

Here's the stack trace:

```
at System.Windows.Threading.Dispatcher.VerifyAccess()
at System.Windows.SystemResources.FindCachedResource(Object key, Object& resource, Boolean mustReturnDeferredResourceReference)
at System.Windows.SystemResources.FindResourceInternal(Object key, Boolean allowDeferredResourceReference, Boolean mustReturnDeferredResourceReference)
at System.Windows.FrameworkElement.FindResourceInternal(FrameworkElement fe, FrameworkContentElement fce, DependencyProperty dp, Object resourceKey, Object unlinkedParent, Boolean allowDeferredResourceReference, Boolean mustReturnDeferredResourceReference, DependencyObject boundaryElement, Boolean isImplicitStyleLookup, Object& source)
at System.Windows.FrameworkElement.FindResource(Object resourceKey)
at Xceed.Wpf.Toolkit.PropertyGrid.PropertyGrid.UpdateContainerHelper()
at Xceed.Wpf.Toolkit.PropertyGrid.PropertyGrid.OnSelectedObjectChanged(Object oldValue, Object newValue)
at Xceed.Wpf.Toolkit.PropertyGrid.PropertyGrid.OnSelectedObjectChanged(DependencyObject o, DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs e)
at System.Windows.DependencyObject.OnPropertyChanged(DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs e)
at System.Windows.FrameworkElement.OnPropertyChanged(DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs e)
at Xceed.Wpf.Toolkit.PropertyGrid.PropertyGrid.OnPropertyChanged(DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs e)
at System.Windows.DependencyObject.NotifyPropertyChange(DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs args)
at System.Windows.DependencyObject.UpdateEffectiveValue(EntryIndex entryIndex, DependencyProperty dp, PropertyMetadata metadata, EffectiveValueEntry oldEntry, EffectiveValueEntry& newEntry, Boolean coerceWithDeferredReference, Boolean coerceWithCurrentValue, OperationType operationType)
at System.Windows.DependencyObject.SetValueCommon(DependencyProperty dp, Object value, PropertyMetadata metadata, Boolean coerceWithDeferredReference, Boolean coerceWithCurrentValue, OperationType operationType, Boolean isInternal)
at System.Windows.DependencyObject.SetValue(DependencyProperty dp, Object value)
at Xceed.Wpf.Toolkit.PropertyGrid.PropertyGrid.set_SelectedObject(Object value)
at GuiHelpers.Dialogs.PropertiesDialog.<>c__DisplayClass11.<Show>b__d() in c:\projects\pro\GuiHelpers\Dialogs\PropertiesDialog.cs:line 44
```

Comment: It could be that Xceed, in the constructor, initializes the SelectedObject using some dispatching mechanism. I don't know why they would do that, but it could explain the behavior.

Answer (score 0):

In case some initialization is performed using a dispatcher to the UI thread you should be able to use something like:

```
System.Windows.Application.Current.Dispatcher.Invoke(
    System.Windows.Threading.DispatcherPriority.Normal,
    (System.Action)delegate()
    {
         tempPropertyGrid.SelectedObject = new object();
    });
```

I'm not sure this solves your problem, but it could be worth a try.